# Can't get read the docs working on my github repo

Tags: git, github, read-the-docs

I'm trying to install read the docs in my repo: https://github.com/robocomp/robocomp/tree/highlyunstable

I have followed this guide: http://tutos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/git_rtd.html

But I always end up with this screen:

[image]
Any idea what am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you create and commit an index.rst or README.rst file, as mentioned in the error message?

Comment: Advice: The way the question is phrased gives the impression that you didn't read and follow instructions. When you encounter an error message, read and act on it be first. Then, when you ask about it here, make sure you  *describe what follow-up actions you have taken*.